# how to make uitextview scroll in iOS Storyboards

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a uitextview with more text that can fit in the view.  I enabled "scrolling enabled" on the textview, however the scrollview does not scroll.

Here is how I populate the textview in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    PFQuery *query = [MyObject query];
    [query whereKey:@"cycleNumber" equalTo:_cycleNumber];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if([objects count] > 0){

            NSString *description = objects[0];

            _lessonDescriptionTextView.text = description;

        }
    }];
```

How can I make the textview scroll to show all content?

Comment: ??? should scroll until you don't have other view over..

Comment: I populate the text from a block.  Could it be the size is already set and I need to the reload the text view after the text is available and populated?

Comment: @MatteoGobbi code is posted

Answer (score 0):

user interaction needs to be enabled!  That was the problem

Comment: i wanted to disable the keyboard so I unchecked that